# rails declarative authorization, permit all actions for controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

using the delcarative_authorization gem for rails, is there a shortcut to allow a role access to all controller actions?

```
privileges do
  # default privilege hierarchies to facilitate RESTful Rails apps
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
end
```

isn't sufficient, because I have more controlling methods than just CRUD in my controllers.

Something like:

```
  role :foo do
    has_permission_on :bar, :to =>[:all]
  end
```

would be perfect, but I'm not finding it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an easy way exists. [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/declarative_authorization/tree/browse_frm/month/2009-04/8a2aba18b47f3bdc?rnum=11&_done=/group/declarative_authorization/browse_frm/month/2009-04%3F) discusses one possible approach: to check for the "master" role and bypass filtering altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
privileges do
  # default privilege hierarchies to facilitate RESTful Rails apps
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  method_names =  Bar.action_methods.to_a
  meths = method_names - %w{create read update delete}
  privilege :all_others, :includes => meths.map{|m| m.to_sym}
end

role :foo do
  has_permission_on :bar, :to =>[:manage,:all_others]
end
```

although something like:

```
privileges do
  # default privilege hierarchies to facilitate RESTful Rails apps
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  privilege :all, :includes => Bar.action_methods
end

role :foo do
  has_permission_on :bar, :to =>[:all]
end
```

might suit your requirements better